# Why does a query using join significantly slower than using subquery?

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery, query-optimization

I'm suprised that my query that uses `join` is about 350 times slower than using subquery.
Usually, I prefer using join because it is more readable. But, the difference in speed is just
too far.

Here's the data definitions. Theses tables are extracted directly from the source code
(except for those lines which are commented below).

```sql
-- possible account type for char of accounts below.
create type account_kind as enum (
  'asset',
  'liability',
  'equity',
  'income',
  'expense'
);

-- chart of accounts represented as a tree.
create table account(
  id        integer      not null,
  name      text         not null,
  kind      account_kind not null,
  parent_id integer,

  constraint account_pkey primary key (id),
  constraint account_name_length_check check (length(name) between 1 and 200),
  constraint account_parent_id_fkey foreign key (parent_id) references account(id) on update cascade on delete restrict,
  constraint account_parent_id_name_uniq unique (parent_id, name),
  constraint account_parent_id_cycle_check check (parent_id <> id)
);

-- a journal represent a single transaction.
-- it always accompanied by at least two posting.
-- at application level, a journal without at least
-- two posting is always rejected.
create table journal(
  id       integer     not null generated always as identity,
--  owner_id integer     not null,
  time     timestamptz not null default current_timestamp,
  text     text        not null,
  amount   numeric     not null,

  constraint journal_pkey primary key (id),
--  constraint journal_owner_id_fkey foreign key (owner_id) references owner(id) on update cascade on delete restrict,
  constraint journal_text_length_check check (length(text) between 1 and 1000),
  constraint journal_amount_sign_check check (amount > 0)
);

-- index on `journal(time asc, id asc)` and `journal(time desc, id desc)` below
-- are used for cursor based pagination. because ordering only using `id` is
-- not meaningful. and `time` is not always in the same order as `id`.

-- create index journal_owner_id_idx on journal(owner_id);
create index journal_time_idx on journal(time);
-- create index journal_text_trgm on journal using gin (text gin_trgm_ops);
create index journal_time_id_asc_idx on journal(time asc, id asc);
create index journal_time_id_desc_idx on journal(time desc, id desc);

-- a posting represent a single entry on journal. this is an implementation
-- of a double entry bookkeeping where postive amount represent a debit entry
-- and negative amount represent a credit entry. this is why zero amount
-- is not allowed.
create table posting(
  id          integer not null generated always as identity,
  journal_id  integer not null,
  account_id  integer not null,
  amount      numeric not null,
  note        text,

  constraint posting_pkey primary key (id),
  constraint posting_journal_id_fkey foreign key (journal_id) references journal(id) on update cascade on delete restrict,
  constraint posting_account_id_fkey foreign key (account_id) references account(id) on update cascade on delete restrict,
  constraint posting_amount_non_zero_check check (amount <> 0),
  constraint posting_note_length_check check (length(note) between 1 and 200)
);

-- don't forget to index foreign keys.
create index posting_journal_id_idx on posting(journal_id);
create index posting_account_id_idx on posting(account_id);
```

Right now, `journal` table contains `43401` rows and `posting` table contains `86802` rows.

The purpose of my query is to fetch data from all those three tables based on `journal` table.

**`JOIN` version**:

```sql
select journal.id,
       journal.time,
       journal.text,
       journal.amount,
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
         'id', posting.id,
         'note', posting.note,
         'amount', posting.amount,
         'account', jsonb_build_object(
           'id', account.id,
           'name', account.name,
           'kind', account.kind,
           'parent_id', account.parent_id
       )) order by posting.id) as postings
  from posting
  join journal on journal.id = posting.journal_id
  join account on account.id = posting.account_id
 where (journal.time, journal.id) >= ('2021-06-01 05:00:00 +00', 2154)
 group by journal.id
 order by journal.time asc, journal.id asc
 limit 100;
```

**subquery version**:

```sql
select journal.id,
       journal.time,
       journal.text,
       journal.amount,
       (select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
                 'id', posting.id,
                 'note', posting.note,
                 'amount', posting.amount,
                 'account', jsonb_build_object(
                   'id', account.id,
                   'name', account.name,
                   'kind', account.kind,
                   'parent_id', account.parent_id
               )) order by posting.id)
          from posting
          join account on posting.account_id = account.id
         where posting.journal_id = journal.id
       ) as postings
  from journal
 where (journal.time, journal.id) >= ('2021-06-01 05:00:00 +00', 2154)
 order by journal.time asc, journal.id asc
 limit 100;
```

Those query produce exactly the same result. It actually possible to produce different result if
there's a `journal` without accompanying `posting`. But, I think that is another story.

The output of running `explain analyze` for the **`JOIN`** version againts the real database is:

```
 Limit  (cost=10252.34..10252.59 rows=100 width=92) (actual time=1293.789..1294.139 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=10252.34..10350.51 rows=39268 width=92) (actual time=1293.787..1293.917 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: journal."time", journal.id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 76kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.73..8751.54 rows=39268 width=92) (actual time=18.876..1244.314 rows=39246 loops=1)
               Group Key: journal.id
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.73..7475.33 rows=78536 width=145) (actual time=18.825..764.928 rows=78492 loops=1)
                     ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.58..5571.84 rows=78536 width=105) (actual time=18.811..396.991 rows=78492 loops=1)
                           Merge Cond: (posting.journal_id = journal.id)
                           ->  Index Scan using posting_journal_id_idx on posting  (cost=0.29..2722.32 rows=86802 width=49) (actual time=0.009..107.108 rows=86802 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using journal_pkey on journal  (cost=0.29..1758.81 rows=39268 width=60) (actual time=0.399..51.562 rows=39246 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ("time" >= '2021-06-01 00:00:00+07'::timestamp with time zone)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 4155
                     ->  Memoize  (cost=0.15..0.17 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=78492)
                           Cache Key: posting.account_id
                           Cache Mode: logical
                           Hits: 78484  Misses: 8  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
                           ->  Index Scan using account_pkey on account  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=8)
                                 Index Cond: (id = posting.account_id)
 Planning Time: 0.207 ms
 Execution Time: 1294.282 ms
```

And the output for **subquery** version is:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.29..981.68 rows=100 width=92) (actual time=0.191..3.437 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using journal_time_id_desc_idx on journal  (cost=0.29..385372.47 rows=39268 width=92) (actual time=0.187..3.203 rows=100 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ("time" >= '2021-06-01 00:00:00+07'::timestamp with time zone)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=9.73..9.74 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.026..0.028 rows=1 loops=100)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.67..9.72 rows=2 width=85) (actual time=0.005..0.012 rows=2 loops=100)
                       Hash Cond: (posting.account_id = account.id)
                       ->  Index Scan using posting_journal_id_idx on posting  (cost=0.29..8.33 rows=2 width=45) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=2 loops=100)
                             Index Cond: (journal_id = journal.id)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=1.17..1.17 rows=17 width=44) (actual time=0.053..0.058 rows=17 loops=1)
                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                             ->  Seq Scan on account  (cost=0.00..1.17 rows=17 width=44) (actual time=0.006..0.027 rows=17 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.615 ms
 Execution Time: 3.598 ms
```

As you can see the difference in `Execution time` is hundred times slower (`1294.282 ms` to `3.598 ms`).

For the purpose of this question, I tried to simulate the query with dummy data
(50000 rows of `journal` and 100000 rows of `posting`):

```sql
insert into account(id, name, kind, parent_id)
values (1,  'Asset',                   'asset',     null),
       (2,    'Cash',                  'asset',     1),
       (3,    'Saving',                'asset',     1),
       (4,  'Liability',               'liability', null),
       (5,    'Payable',               'liability', 4),
       (6,  'Equity',                  'equity',    null),
       (7,    'Capital',               'equity',    6),
       (8,  'Income',                  'income',    null),
       (9,    'Operating Income',      'income',    8),
       (10,   'Non Operating Income',  'income',    8),
       (11, 'Expense',                 'expense',   null),
       (12,   'Operating Expense',     'expense',   11),
       (13,   'Non Operating Expense', 'expense',   12);

insert into journal(time, text, amount)
-- random transactions for every 30 minutes from 2020-01-01 00:00:00 +00
select to_timestamp(1577836800 + 1800 * n),
       'Transaction' || to_char(n, '0000'),
       floor(random() * 1000) + 1
  from generate_series(1, 50000) as series(n);

insert into posting(journal_id, account_id, amount)
select journal.id,
      -- random account_id
       floor(random() * 13) + 1,
       case n % 2
         when 0 then journal.amount
         when 1 then journal.amount * -1
       end as amount
  from generate_series(1, 100000) as series(n)
  join journal on journal.id = floor((n + 1) / 2)
 order by journal.id;
```

Running `explain analyze` with simulated data give me slightly different result.

**`join`** version:

```
 Limit  (cost=4248.40..4248.65 rows=100 width=108) (actual time=927.635..927.991 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4248.40..4275.50 rows=10842 width=108) (actual time=927.632..927.769 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: journal."time", journal.id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 76kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=3491.47..3834.02 rows=10842 width=108) (actual time=534.029..895.869 rows=25175 loops=1)
               Group Key: journal.id
               ->  Sort  (cost=3491.47..3532.88 rows=16562 width=188) (actual time=533.982..594.864 rows=50350 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: journal.id
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4592kB
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=1022.89..2330.84 rows=16562 width=188) (actual time=176.058..467.650 rows=50350 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (posting.account_id = account.id)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=987.47..2251.78 rows=16562 width=148) (actual time=176.014..351.375 rows=50350 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (posting.journal_id = journal.id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on posting  (cost=0.00..1133.86 rows=49686 width=76) (actual time=0.004..114.328 rows=100000 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=851.94..851.94 rows=10842 width=76) (actual time=61.709..61.716 rows=25175 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 32768 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1977kB
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on journal  (cost=272.31..851.94 rows=10842 width=76) (actual time=0.553..31.249 rows=25175 loops=1)
                                             Filter: (ROW("time", id) >= ROW('2021-06-01 12:00:00+07'::timestamp with time zone, 2154))
                                             Heap Blocks: exact=211
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on journal_time_idx  (cost=0.00..269.60 rows=10842 width=0) (actual time=0.533..0.535 rows=25175 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: ("time" >= '2021-06-01 12:00:00+07'::timestamp with time zone)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=21.30..21.30 rows=1130 width=44) (actual time=0.037..0.041 rows=13 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on account  (cost=0.00..21.30 rows=1130 width=44) (actual time=0.002..0.016 rows=13 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.120 ms
 Execution Time: 928.739 ms
```

**subquery** version:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.29..52688.73 rows=100 width=108) (actual time=0.133..3.602 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using journal_time_id_asc_idx on journal  (cost=0.29..5712480.93 rows=10842 width=108) (actual time=0.129..3.370 rows=100 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (ROW("time", id) >= ROW('2021-06-01 12:00:00+07'::timestamp with time zone, 2154))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=526.68..526.69 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=100)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=45.64..524.82 rows=248 width=112) (actual time=0.008..0.015 rows=2 loops=100)
                       Hash Cond: (posting.account_id = account.id)
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posting  (cost=10.21..488.74 rows=248 width=72) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=2 loops=100)
                             Recheck Cond: (journal_id = journal.id)
                             Heap Blocks: exact=101
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on posting_journal_id_idx  (cost=0.00..10.15 rows=248 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=100)
                                   Index Cond: (journal_id = journal.id)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=21.30..21.30 rows=1130 width=44) (actual time=0.042..0.046 rows=13 loops=1)
                             Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
                             ->  Seq Scan on account  (cost=0.00..21.30 rows=1130 width=44) (actual time=0.002..0.019 rows=13 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.202 ms
 Execution Time: 3.757 ms
```

The difference is `928.739 ms` to `3.757 ms` (almost 250 times slower).

I don't understand. Why is the difference so significant? Is my `join` query wrong?

Comment: These queries are not the same: The subquery might return a JSON, depending on the results of the subquery, for a maximum of 100 records it finds in "journal". The query using a JOIN must first create a large set of data to find all related data, then create a JSON and then sort and limit the results. You can see the difference when you delete all data in the table "posting" or "account".

Comment: "But, I think that is another story"  Why?  The database can't generate fast plans which lead to the wrong answer, just because they will be right *some* of the time.

Comment: @jjanes it's not _some_ time. Join and subquery work differently. Without accompanying child table, join won't include missing row in child table and subquery will (with null value in the corresponding field).